# Is there a way I can setup default graphs via the MLFlow API

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, mlflow, mlops

I create a new 'experiment' every time I change the validation set (which is often), but each time I want basically the same graphs. This is the easiest way for me to make relevant comparisons across training runs. Is there a way to set these up via the API, so that I don't have to click away on the UI every time?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean "create experiment" through mlflow API, you could check the following page:

https://mlflow.org/docs/latest/rest-api.html#create-experiment

```
2.0/mlflow/experiments/create
```

It will return experiment_id which could be used later.

Also supported in python code:

```
import mlflow

mlflow.start_run()

experiment_name = "EXAMPLE"

experiment = mlflow.get_experiment_by_name(experiment_name)
if experiment is None:
    experiment_id = mlflow.create_experiment(experiment_name)
else:
    experiment_id = experiment.experiment_id

# log metrics
with mlflow.start_run(experiment_id=experiment_id):
    mlflow.log_metric("accuracy", 0.1)
    mlflow.log_artifact("path/to/artifact/file")

mlflow.end_run()
```

Comment: Doesn't look like that does the trick. I can create experiments fine. It's setting up the right graphs for each experiment that's the pain.

Comment: Could you explain more or share figure for the UI?